# Android Espresso not able to test fragement

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, mockk

I am trying to launch a fragment as below

```
    private lateinit var homeFragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<HomeFragment>

    @MockK
    lateinit var mockPool: UserPool


@Before
fun setUp() {
    InjectMocksRule.createMockK(this)
    ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    homeFragmentScenario= launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme)
    homeFragmentScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    Intents.init()

}


    @Test
fun loadScreen() {
    every { mockPool.userId } answers {"123456"}
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.layout_home))
        .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
}
```

This is the activity code where i am getting error

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)
    
    menuNotification.icon = NotificationHelper.getNotificationDrawable(UserPool.userId )

}
```

I want to know how to provide the dummy userid when i am trying to test this fragment.

**How can i stub or do any action to pass a dummy value like**

```
every { mockPool.userId } answers {"123456"}
```

Comment: There are some questions you should clarify. Why did not you call `MockKAnnotations.init(this, ...` on `@Before`? Where are you using `mockPool` and why userId is String? What is `UserPool.userId`?

Comment: I forgot to add here but i have added it updating post

Comment: UserPool.userid is AWS user pool from where we are getting user id

Answer (score 0):

Without having full code, I assume that `UserPool` is a kotlin object singleton.
You do not need `lateinit var mockPool: UserPool` because `mockPool` is not used in your test code and NotificationHelper uses directly `UserPool` object.

Here a simple test.

```kotlin
@Test
  fun loadScreen() {
    mockkObject(UserPool)

    every { UserPool.userId } answers { "123456" }

    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.layout_home))
        .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
    
    // We have to verify that UserPool.userId is called
    // because we are mocking it by purpose
    verify(exactly = 1) { UserPool.userId }

    // It is advised to unmock objects 
    // otherwise other tests make fail or success falsely
    unmockkObject(UserPool)
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)  App is crashing at this line when test is run not able to reach till fun loadScreen()

Comment: When i add this mockkObject(UserPool) i am getting function invocation expected error

Comment: Your question was about how to mock UserPool.userId. I gave this example without knowing your implementation. It may be worth to test mock UserPool without Expresso test. When you achieve this you can integrate it in Espresso test. Seemingly, your espresso test implementation is also failing.